# GCP bucket leaf level node file along with full path

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are having million of million objects in many buckets and project. We need to get the leaf level information for all the buckets across all projects. gsutil is does it but it's too slow. we have tried with storage api and it's slow as it has to traverse folder prefix and then leaf node so it's too slow. Is there any other quick method to get leaf leave node details

Example

Bucket/Folder1/Subfodler1/Subfolder2/Subfodler3/Subfodler4/Subfodler5/File.txt

Basically, we want to get the size and other details about the leaf node file. the challenge ist that 500+ million numbers of records need to extract.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage is a blob storage. That means each object are leaf. Directory doesn't exist, it's only object with the same prefix.

So, you haven't other solution than to scan all the files ([bucket object list API call](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#rest-list-objects)). And to call [metadata API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata) to get the size of the object.

So, 1 API call to get a pageable list of object, and then another call to get the size of the object. About 150ms per object.

---

Now that you know how work the GCS platform, you can design your app to massively parallelize the calls and speed up the process. But there is nothing magic. 500million object will take time to scan!